# Yahoo server PHP problem. PHP script can't LOAD file with Yahoo server that supports PHP 7.26

Tags: php, server, yahoo

script file: getrss.php
snippet:

```
$xml="http://www.cbsnews.com/latest/rss/world";
$xmlDoc = new DOMDocument();
$xmlDoc->load($xml) or die($xml);
```

the same script works with two other hosts:
http://paradigmparadigm.com/getrss.php?q=CBS
http://paradigmparadigm.rocks/getrss.php?q=CBS

Comment: Your script works, and loads the data into the $xmlDoc object, but you are not outputing it anywhere? I assume this is not the whole script? you can do `print_r($xmlDoc);` to see that your info is indeed there. What is the actual error? What is the actual expected result? Examples?

Comment: These links run the complete code:http://paradigmparadigm.com/getrss.php?q=CBS http://paradigmparadigm.rocks/getrss.php?q=CBS